# Spotfire: Binning based on percentage

Tags: spotfire, binning

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QRqI.png)

I have a column which consist of Primary and Secondary groups like the example above, what I would like to do is to group all Secondary groups into Primary group, so that the final column will only consist of all Primary groups. However, I need to divide some of the Secondary group's value by percentage among the Primary groups, for example: 50% of Secondary D goes to Primary A and B respectively, 1/3 of Secondary E goes to Primary A, B and C respectively and all of Secondary F goes into Primary C. The end results will look something like the table below.

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAMUD.png)

Could someone give me some pointers on how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

DL

Comment: Will there ever be more groups than those listed?

Comment: Actually there are more but I'm simplifying the example so that it is easier to understand, in fact, there are more columns in my actual scenario, so eventually, what I'm trying to do is for the row with has the "Secondary group", I need to split it into a few similar rows, with the only difference being the "Column" and "Value" field, which will split into respective "Primary" group and "Value"

Comment: That's fine, but with more secondary and primary groups, you will have to hard code the relation. I can provide an answer for this dataset but it won't be a plug and play for your other dataset--it will just show you a single method.

Comment: I think I've figured out how to solve my problem, basically I just need to create new columns based on the few primary groups, and map the secondary groups value to the new primary groups column. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Be sure to post your answer for us to see :)